# SQL Server Query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I need a sql query to get records on the basis of multiple tables. Like below -

There are tables Table_A, Table_B & Table_C. In which Table_A is the main table in which I want to get the data. And Table_B is dependent on Table_A, containing the Foreign Key of Table_A.

Table_A (parent table) ----> Table_B(child table)

And Table_C is contains the Foreign key of table Table_B.

Table_B (parent table) ----> Table_C(child table)

So now I need a data from Table_A and one of the column of Table_C. But that column will contain the comma separate string on the basis of Table_A's primary key value.

Comment: can you provide data example and desired output please

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: you should first start looking at JOIN (inner join). You should also avoid comma separated string in a table, especially if you need to query some of the separated values in the string.

Comment: Ugh. Delimited strings in sql are a very bad design decision and violates 1NF. It forces you to constantly split those into values you can actually use. You should start by getting that delimited data into something persistent and normalized. Then this query is no longer challenging.

Answer (score 0):

> So now I need a data from Table_A and one of the column of Table_C.
>   But that column will contain the comma separate string on the basis of
>   Table_A's primary key value.

This is the wrong way to solve your abstract problem.  If you want multiple items in Table C to be associated with Table A (and based on the comment above Table B has no effect) then you should do the following:

Create a table called CjoinA which has an ID_C and an ID_A a column  Then there will be multiple rows for the relations ship so if Table C row ID 1 is related to rows of Table A with IDs 1, 2 and 3 then you would have three rows like this

```
ID_C    ID_A
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to create a function which concats the values of `table_C`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_TBC](@parentID Integer) 
returns nvarchar(MAX) 
Begin 
    declare @result as varchar(MAX) 
    set @result = ''  
    select @result =  @result + _YOURCOLUMN_ + '; ' 
    from TABLE_C 
    WHERE PARENT_ID_COL = @parentID  

    select @result =  left (@result , len(@result )-1);    
    return @result 
end
```

and use this function in your select statement:

```
SELECT TableA.*, GET_TBC(TableB.ID)
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableB.ParentID = TableA.ID
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the what the OP wants but if it is it is a horrible way to get this result.  You should use the FOR XML trick which is a number of orders of magnitude faster.